# AtTiny214 can't change waveform output pins

Tags: microcontroller, avr, embedded

I am trying to program my AtTiny214 (TinyAVR1 Series chip, SOIC-14 version, relevant datasheet: [Datasheet](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATtiny212-214-412-414-416-DataSheet-DS40002287A.pdf)) so that I have 2 PWM outputs with different duty cycles.

My problem is:

Changing the contents of the `TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLB` register does not change the output location of the generated waveform. Enabling all outputs in the register does not work either. I made sure to set all the involved ports as outputs, but I only get a waveform on WO0 and WO3.

I would appreciate any kind of help or ideas!

Code:

```
TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLD = TCA_SINGLE_SPLITM_bm;   //split mode enable
TCA0.SPLIT.HPER = 100;      //period of both waveforms: 100
TCA0.SPLIT.LPER = 100;
TCA0.SPLIT.HCMP0 = 25;      //duty cycle of individual waveforms: 25%, 75%
TCA0.SPLIT.LCMP0 = 75;
//TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLB = 0b01110111;            //WO0-2 WO3-5
TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLB = 0b00010001;              //WO3 WO0
TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLA = TCA_SPLIT_ENABLE_bm;     //split enable
PORTB.DIRSET = PIN0_bm | PIN1_bm | PIN2_bm;   //WO0-2 outputs
PORTA.DIRSET = PIN3_bm | PIN4_bm | PIN5_bm;   //WO3-5
```

Comment: Have you checked out the relevant [errata document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny214_414_814-Errata-and-Clarification-DS40002115B.pdf) for any mention of the issues you are seeing? Section 2.6.1 seems to mention something similar.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I have checked that, but this would only apply if I tried to change my WO pins to their alternate ones. In my case, I'm still only using the default pinout. But still, thank you very much for your input.

Comment: What about TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLD.SPLITM? You need to set that bit to operate the timer as two separate 8-bit timers. TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLA.ENABLE only enables the timer in general, it doesn't enable split mode.

Comment: @JonathanS. I had that, but due to bad formatting of my code block here (sorry, first time posting) it was not visible. Thank you for your input, however in the meantime I managed to find the solution, which I wrote in a separate answer. Thanks again! (Also edited my post so it displays my code correctly.)

Comment: That's great! Don't forget to accept your own answer; as you already pointed out, it's very likely to be useful to someone else in the future. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, I found out that the `WOn` output is only affected by the `TCA0.SPLIT.LCMPn`, and the `WO[3+n]` outputs by `TCA0.SPLIT.HCMPn`.

By setting `TCA0.SPLIT.LCMP1` to a desired value, and `TCA0.SPLIT.LCMP0` to 0, I could freely change the output pin from PB0 to PB1. I hope this helps out someone with this problem in the future :)

Some code:

```
int main() {
  TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLD = TCA_SINGLE_SPLITM_bm;   //split mode
  TCA0.SPLIT.HPER = 100;      //period
  TCA0.SPLIT.LPER = 100;
  TCA0.SPLIT.HCMP0 = 5;      //duty cycle of the WO3 output (PA3 by default)
  TCA0.SPLIT.LCMP0 = 75;     //duty cycle of WO0 (PB0)
  TCA0.SPLIT.LCMP2 = 30;     //duty cycle of WO2 (PB2)
  TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLB = TCA_SPLIT_HCMP0EN_bm | TCA_SPLIT_LCMP0EN_bm | TCA_SPLIT_LCMP2EN_bm; //we are using HCMP0, LCMP0 and LCMP2
  TCA0.SPLIT.CTRLA = TCA_SPLIT_ENABLE_bm;     //split enable
  PORTB.DIRSET = PIN0_bm | PIN2_bm;   //WO0 and WO2 outputs
  PORTA.DIRSET = PIN3_bm;   //WO3 output
  while(1);
}
```